# Laravel: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform

Tags: php, laravel, windows-10

I'm trying to use the "php artisan db" command and I'm getting this error. How can I fix it? I've already seen some similar problems, but none of them helped me.

```
PS C:\Users\Alisson\Documents\Programming stuff\study\first-laravel-crud> php artisan db

   Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException 

  TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.

  at C:\Users\Alisson\Documents\Programming stuff\study\first-laravel-crud\vendor\symfony\process\Process.php:1059
    1055▕      */
    1056▕     public function setTty(bool $tty)
    1057▕     {
    1058▕         if ('\\' === \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR && $tty) {
  ➜ 1059▕             throw new RuntimeException('TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform.');
    1060▕         }
    1061▕
    1062▕         if ($tty && !self::isTtySupported()) {
    1063▕             throw new RuntimeException('TTY mode requires /dev/tty to be read/writable.');

  1   C:\Users\Alisson\Documents\Programming stuff\study\first-laravel-crud\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\DbCommand.php:41
      Symfony\Component\Process\Process::setTty()

  2   C:\Users\Alisson\Documents\Programming stuff\study\first-laravel-crud\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
      Illuminate\Database\Console\DbCommand::handle()
```

Comment: As a Windows-based developer I’ve found a couple of things that have sometimes worked (but not always) for general CLI issues, not necessarily this specific one. One is to use `php.exe` instead of just `php`, another is to use the full absolute path to the binary. Also, try a different terminal/shell. I use GitBash (awesome) as a shell, usually in Windows Terminal (not great, but better than the default) but sometimes standalone. Lastly, try [piping through ANSICON](https://cjhaas.com/2021/09/01/windows-terminal-gitbash-colors/)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is to use Linux for development, which is (I assume) fairly easily done using Windows' [built-in facilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about).

But, all `php artisan db` does is call the MySQL command line, which you can  do yourself. Check your `.env` file to get values for the host, username, and password. Then fill them into this command:

```sh
mysql -h host -u username -ppassword
```

Note the missing space after -p is intentional.

Comment: type the following command in the vscode terminal. 'mysql -u username -p'. It will ask for password and logs you in